# Certutil with Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

Trying to encode all my *.pdf and *docx within a folder and its subdirectories, to base64. So far, since the certutil specifies "from source" "to destination" or an overwrite with -f switch, am clueless on how to get this working, even with a FOR loop. Thanks for your help.

Thanks putu. Corrections taken. Well, am trying to overwrite the existing documents to its base64 encoding which I've been successful in doing one document at a time. The challenge is in automating the process into all documents in folders and sub-folders. I've tried using the the "for" statement:

for /R %%a in (*.docx, *.pdf) do certutil -f -encode %%a %%a.

This was just a test as certutil don't have any syntax for encoding multiple files at once.

Comment: Your requirement (thus the question) is unclear. Do you want to encode the documents to different file OR overwrite existing file OR save the result to different directory? If it's in batch file, add `batch-file` tag, so your question will be available to more competence members. I also suggest you to show your code so far, and ask for the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

The /R function of the for loop returns the full file spec including the drive and path. I suspect either the path or file name contains one or more spaces so they need to be quoted. Use the following:

```
for /R %%a in (*.docx, *.pdf) do certutil -f -encode "%%a" "%%a"
```

Comment: Wow...this worked! Thanks a million. Running the command without the quotes in %%a variable flags an error from certutil saying: "too many arguments" which is somewhat misleading. Thanks for the clarification.